# Solve the functional equation $f(x)=f\left({x\over 3}\right)+f\left({2x\over 3}\right)$ with $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ continuous

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, problem-solving

Solve the functional equation

> $$f(x)=f\left({x\over 3}\right)+f\left({2x\over 3}\right)\qquad \forall x\geq 0$$ 
>   with $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ continuous.

I can't manage to get this one to the form of [Cauchy's functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), but I imagine that's how it's maybe done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To my surprise, there are non-linear solutions to this functional equation.
Consider functions of the form:

$$F(x;\alpha,k) = x^\alpha \sin( k\log x )$$

If one can choose $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and $k \in (0,\infty)$ such that:

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac13\right)^\alpha \cos\left(k \log\frac13\right) + \left(\frac23\right)^\alpha \cos\left(k\log\frac23\right) &= 1\\
\left(\frac13\right)^\alpha \sin\left(k \log\frac13\right) + \left(\frac23\right)^\alpha \sin\left(k\log\frac23\right) &= 0\tag{*}
\end{align}$$

then $F$ is continuous over $[0,\infty)$ and satisfies:
$$ F(x;\alpha,k) =  F(\frac{x}{3};\alpha,k) + F(\frac{2x}{3};\alpha,k)$$

By trial and error, I find at least one solution of $(*)$ with $(\alpha,k) \sim ( 0.7586093, 16.4941542 )$ and the corresponding $f(x)$ looks like this:

[image: A strange beast]

Comment: No surprise nobody, to begin with me, managed to prove the only solutions are linear... Congrats, +1.

Comment: well that's unexpected, since even the book I found the problem in they only offered the linear solution, even though there was no proof. so your counter-example is impressive, thanks :)

Comment: +1 Your approach is quite impressive! I also suspected a counter-example, but I have never imagined that such a simple counter-example could be available!

Comment: @Andreea I've thought about this a little bit more. The condition $(*)$ can be simplified to $$\left(\frac13\right)^\beta + \left(\frac23\right)^\beta = 1$$ where $\beta = \alpha + i k$. If one approach the problem using complex numbers, the answer no longer look that surprising. I now wonder whether there are infinitely many such $\beta$....

Comment: +1 very nice solution, much easier than i was searching for

Comment: Even though I don't have a rigorous proof, I've convinced myself there are infinitely many solutions for $(\alpha,k)$. If one perform a parametric plot $\left(\frac13\right)^\beta + \left(\frac23\right)^\beta$ for $\beta$ along the imaginary axis. One can see the graph wraps around $1$ infinitely many times. If one do the same thing for $\beta$ varies from $1 + \epsilon - i\infty$ to $1 + \epsilon + i\infty$, the graph falls inside the unit circle. This implies there are infinitely many roots of $(*)$ for $0 < \alpha < 1 + \epsilon$.

Comment: Complex solutions of $$\left(\frac13\right)^\beta + \left(\frac23\right)^\beta = 1$$ are called by Michel Lapidus **complex dimensions** for the IFS with ratios $1/3$ and $2/3$.  See his book: Lapidus & van Frankenhuysen, *Fractal Geometry and Number Theory*, chapter 1.

Comment: @GEdgar Interesting, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

We surely know that $f(0)=0$ as 
$$f(0)=f(0)+f(0)$$
An obvious solution is $f(x)=x$, and multiple of that $f(x)=\alpha x$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Do you need all solutions, or a proof that this are all functions? Or do you just need to find a single solution?

I am not sure if it is the unique solution, I give you some of my thoughts.
(In fact this reminds me  a bit  at devils staircase (the cantor function)  an so I think the solution will not be unique).
We have the equation
\[ f(x)=f(\tfrac{x}{3}) + f(\tfrac{2x}{3})\]

This means that 
$$f(x)-f(\tfrac{x}{3})=f(\tfrac{2x}{3})$$

Using the equation above again we have
\[ f(x)=f(\tfrac{x}{9}) + f(\tfrac{2x}{9}) + f(\tfrac{2x}{9}) + f(\tfrac{4x}{9})\]
This is obvious equal to
\[ f(x) = f(\tfrac{x}{9}) +2 f(\tfrac{2x}{9}) + f(\tfrac{4x}{9})\]
When we iterate this one again we get
\[ f(x) = f(\tfrac{x}{27}) + 3 f(\tfrac{2x}{27}) +3f(\tfrac{4x}{27})+ f(\tfrac{8x}{27})\]
More general we have
\[ f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} f\left(\frac{2^i x}{3^i}\right)\]

Comment: all the continuous solutions, yes, or proof that that one is unique

Comment: The expansion $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} f(\frac{2^ix}{3^n})$ implies if $f'(0+) = \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists and equal to $c$, then $f(x) = cx$. However, I can't figure out any reason why this limit has to exist.

Comment: @achillehui jupp i am having the same problem right now. Is there a good reason for our function to be lipschitzcontinuous? and will lipschitz continuous imply that the limit exists (right now i just think of the abs value function ... ^^ )

Answer (score -1):

Observe that : $$f(x)=f\left(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{2x}{3}\right)=f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+f\left(\frac{2x}{3}\right)$$

you can make a substitution :

$$\frac{x}{3}=y;$$
$$\frac{2x}{3}=z.$$

$$f(y+z)=f(y)+f(z)$$ which is a Cauchy functional equation with  the solution: 
$$f(y)=Ky, K \in \mathbb{R}.$$

or $$f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=\frac{x}{3}$$ 
$$\frac{x}{3} \mapsto X $$

so $$f(X)=kX$$ with $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: and yet between $x/3$ and $2x/3$ we have the relation $2*(x/3)=2x/3$ and to apply the Cauchy equation we need -any- y,z $[0,\infty)$. For example, take 2 and 3, how do you show that $f(2+3)=f(2)+f(3)$ from just $f(x)=f(x/3)+f(2x/3)$?

Comment: In the Cauchy equation, $(y, z)$ can assume any point in $\Bbb{R}^2$. Otherwise, in this case, the possible choices of $(y, z)$ are restricted to a certain subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ satisfying $z = 2y$. This problem is certainly not reducible to the ordinary Cauchy functional equation problem.

Comment: @sos440 yes, but I'm looking for a proof which takes advantage of the continuity somehow and proves that if f(x+2x)=f(x)+f(2x) then f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) for any real positive x,y, if such a proof is possible

Comment: @Andreea, I certainly agree that the continuity assumption is such a condition that is powerful enough to possibly yield the linearity. But I'm now sure whether the answer is yes or not.